# How to detect if any of 2 columns in a Pandas data frame (with N columns) have a parent-child relationship?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hierarchy

I need to **efficiently** detect if any pair of 2 columns in a data frame has a parent/child relationship. The purpose is to automatically detect all such relations in a data frame. The data frame is not known beforehand. Efficiently, because I already known that N*(N-1)*2 column-to-column investigations need to be executed. Below there is a sample dataset for this tricky problem. Ideally there would be a function that returns all column pairs that constitute a parent child relation, e.g.

`resolve_parent_child_dependencies(df)`

For the sample below (ignoring all the other columns) this should return

`[(col1, col2), (col1, col3), (col1, col4),(col1, colN) (col2, col3), ..., (colN, col4)]`

Here's the sample dataset.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 ... colN
   A   A1  A11  foo        X        
   A   A2  A21  bar        Y
   A   A2  A22  foo        X
   B   B1  B11  baz        Z
   B   B2  B21  qux        Z
   B   B3  B22  baz        Z
```

Purpose is to turn *any* pandas data frame without much configuration into a multi-dimensional database (the one im currently developing, https://tinyolap.com). The function is needed to auto-detect all the relationships to derive the dimensional model from the data frame.

Any ideas to get me restarted? 100x thanks...

Comment: what constitutes a parent/child relationship?

Comment: Each parent can have 1 to N children. Each child can only have 1 parent. parent:child := 1:n.  If we find a single n:m or only 1:1 relations, then it's not a parent child relation. So if we have two columns and just find a single 1:N and the rest 1:1, then its already a parent child relation. The number of 1:N relations must be >= 1.

Comment: You are explaining the constraints, which I guess are useful. But still, what makes a column the parent of another column? length of the strings? contains the other column's string?

Comment: Hi @rcshon, thanks for taking this up! There is no special characteristics other than the constrains mentioned. Columns can even haven different value types. So, this a totally generic problem - unfortunately.